# How to get macOS to play audio-in from aux

Tags: audio, bluetooth

When I am on my PS4, I cannot get the sound to play through my Bluetooth speaker. What I want to do instead is to connect the PS4 controller to my MacBook Pro via the 3.5mm jack and then use some software to forward that to my Bluetooth speaker.

How would I get the audio from the 3.5mm jack going from my PS4 controller  to my Mac, again, from the 3.5mm jack?

Here is a diagram of what I want to make it easier to understand.

PS4 Controller-->3.5mm jack--->MacBook Pro-->Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

You can use an application like [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com).

1. Connect your PS4 controller via the 3.5 mm jack to your MacBook.
2. Open Airfoil, select Audio Source: External Microphone
3. Select Transmit to: (Your Bluetooth Speaker)
4. Enable your Bluetooth device.

Comment: Unfortunantly, it does not work. The reason why is probaly because it is the from the audio line on the jack and not the microphone inside it.

Comment: @iProgram If you connect a microphone to a MacBooks 3.5 mm jack it will automatically detect whether it's a source (mic) or a receiver (headphones).

Comment: The program unfortunately does not detect that then. I used the microphone input, however it did not go through to the output which was a Bluetooth speaker.